# Clicking on the Stack Exchange site advertisement in the side bar, loads the Stack Overflow site in the advertisement place holder

Tags: bug, advertising, sidebar, site-ads

There is one of the Stack Exchange site advertisement in the Stack Overflow sidebar (probably writing.stackexchange.com), when I clicked on the advertisement, instead of redirecting to the advertisement site, it loads the Stack Overflow site in the advertisement place holder.

I faced the same issue few days before with the ell.stackexchange.com advertisement in the Stack Overflow sidebar.

The issue occurred after clicking on the advertisement, so I don't have much information about the URLs. I'm using Mozilla Firefox (can't confirm it reproduced in Google Chrome too).

The screenshot taken after clicked on the advertisement:

> [image: Ad]

---

**Update:**

Today I got a chance to see another Stack Exchange advertisement in the side bar and able to record that.

> [image: Ad GIF]

The URL used for the advertisement is

> [image: Ad URL]

in the plain text:

> https://stackoverflow.com/?url=https://serverfault.com/questions/975594/why-is-google-approaching-my-vps-machine

Comment: I am using Google Chrome and this issue has also encountered multiple times for me.

Comment: [Same issue here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388968/craftcms-stackexchange-ad-broken) (marked as duplicate, but for anyone looking for more info).

Comment: [Same issue here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389255/clicking-on-an-ad-replaced-itself-with-so-page-in-that-small-place) as well.

Comment: [Same issue here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334794/clicking-community-promotion-ad-renders-an-instance-of-so-within-the-frame-of-th) MSE cross-dupe

Comment: I just created [a duplicate question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397071/cannot-click-hot-network-question-ads) about this. Sorry! But, how is it possible that the Stack Overflow developers have not been able to fix this bug after almost a year?!

Comment: Just added another [duplicate question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400423/side-ad-link-opens-in-the-wrong-place?noredirect=1#comment790368_400423) (swear i tried to search but didn't find this one!). Any info on the issue?

Comment: I have the same issue using Vivaldi.

Comment: One more [duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401587/916225) from me.