# Clicking on an ad replaced itself with SO page in that small place!

Tags: bug, advertising

I was on Stack Overflow's question page when I happened to see an ad that quoted something along these lines:

> How to split the string by third (.) delimiter
>
> Unix * Linux

Clicking on it replaced that ad with an SO page reopening inside that box. See the image:

[image]

I am not getting that ad back, so I don't really know what caused this behavior.

Browser: Chrome 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Windows 10

Update: See another image: [image]

Comment: Possibly related [bug report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387296/11682469).

Comment: Are you using an ad-blocker or is there anything else in your network that block certain sites?

Comment: Nop I am not using any kind of blocker

Comment: Hmm, strange. I would expect that if everything loads this shouldn't happen.