# Cannot click hot network question "ads"

Tags: bug, sidebar

Sometimes, there is an "ad" displaying a hot Stack Exchange question in the right sidebar. And sometimes, it makes me curious and so I click on it.

But this doesn't take me to the SE question. Instead, the ad area is replaced by a Stack Overflow header:

[image: A sidebar ad that, when clicked, is replaced by a Stack Overflow header.]

I suspect this is not the intended behaviour. I'm on Firefox 75 (64-bit), Windows 7 (64-bit).