# Side ad link opens in the wrong place

Tags: bug, advertising

Not always, but sometimes I see ads on the right that point to other SE sites with hot questions and similar.

The problem is that when I try to open such link, it opens it in the space of the ad, the ad is served in an iframe and the link is opened in that same iframe.

This obviously is a problem because I am not able to actually visit the question in the ad.

The ad is the one in this image:

[image]

And when I click on the link, this happens:

[image]

Note that when a normal ad is served in the same place, not a SE question, the link opens as usual in another tab.

I am using Chrome Version 84.0.4147.125 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10.