# Advertisement when clicked loaded stackoverflow in a frame

Tags: bug, advertising

Today I was browsing Stack Overflow, and there was an ad for a [world-building site](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour). When clicked, it loaded Stack Overflow in a frame.

[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is now itself an ad on Stack Overflow. Is that Inception?

Comment: It might lead to a stack overflow. That would be Inception.

Comment: What is a *"word-building site"*? Do you mean a *"[worldbuilding site](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour)"* (an extra [letter "l"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/L#Letter))? You can [edit your question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/401587/edit).